# Binance OCO Order -> MIN_NOTIONAL | python-binance

Tags: python, binance

Im trying to create an OCO order for `ETHUSDT`

This is the function I created:

```
def OcoOrder(symbol, bet, takeProfit, stopLoss):
    client.order_oco_sell(symbol=symbol,
                          quantity=str(bet),
                          price=str(round(takeProfit, 2)),
                          stopPrice=str(round(stopLoss, 2)),
                          stopLimitPrice =str(round(stopLoss, 2)),
                          stopLimitTimeInForce="GTC")
```

Heres the call:

```
buyPrice = 3803.57
stopLossValue = buyPrice * stopLoss
takeProfitValue = buyPrice * takeProfit
OcoOrder(symbol, "0.0028", takeProfitValue, stopLossValue)
```

The quantity Im having is 0.0028 which equals a bit more than 10USDT
[image]

**After I execute the code I get the error:**

```
APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: MIN_NOTIONAL
```

I checked the binance exchange information for the `MIN_NOTINAL` value and it is 10. Means the minimum quantity i can sell is 10 ETH or in other words 38.000€ ?!?!?!

```
{
     "symbol":"ETHUSDT",
     "status":"TRADING",
     "baseAsset":"ETH",
     "baseAssetPrecision":8,
     "quoteAsset":"USDT",
     "quotePrecision":8,
     "quoteAssetPrecision":8,
     "baseCommissionPrecision":8,
     "quoteCommissionPrecision":8,
     "orderTypes":[
        "LIMIT",
        "LIMIT_MAKER",
        "MARKET",
        "STOP_LOSS_LIMIT",
        "TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT"
     ],
     "icebergAllowed":true,
     "ocoAllowed":true,
     "quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed":true,
     "isSpotTradingAllowed":true,
     "isMarginTradingAllowed":true,
     "filters":[
        {
           "filterType":"PRICE_FILTER",
           "minPrice":"0.01000000",
           "maxPrice":"1000000.00000000",
           "tickSize":"0.01000000"
        },
        {
           "filterType":"PERCENT_PRICE",
           "multiplierUp":"5",
           "multiplierDown":"0.2",
           "avgPriceMins":5
        },
        {
           "filterType":"LOT_SIZE",
           "minQty":"0.00010000",
           "maxQty":"9000.00000000",
           "stepSize":"0.00010000"
        },
        {
           "filterType":"MIN_NOTIONAL",
           "minNotional":"10.00000000",
           "applyToMarket":true,
           "avgPriceMins":5
        },
        {
           "filterType":"ICEBERG_PARTS",
           "limit":10
        },
        {
           "filterType":"MARKET_LOT_SIZE",
           "minQty":"0.00000000",
           "maxQty":"1459.84229583",
           "stepSize":"0.00000000"
        },
        {
           "filterType":"MAX_NUM_ORDERS",
           "maxNumOrders":200
        },
        {
           "filterType":"MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS",
           "maxNumAlgoOrders":5
        }
     ],
     "permissions":[
        "SPOT",
        "MARGIN"
     ]
  },
```

If I swap it around and use the USDT value as the quantity I get `Account has insufficient balance for requested action.` because Im obviously not having 10 ETH

**Am I overseeing something? It cant be true that the minimum qty is 10 ETH**

Answer (score 3):

Min notational is measured in dollars, not quantity of the coin. This order must have just been on the cusp of that level that it was getting rejected. I tried your code and it worked. I then scaled down in increments of .0001 and got min notational error as I neared $10.

The main thing to consider here is your stop loss, which also cannot fall below min notational as you are effectively putting in an order for x amount minus losses, which likely took you over. Just need to trade a bit more as to give yourself a buffer.

Cheers friend!

Comment: Right the buy order was correct but the stop loss sell would have been below the 10. It works with a bigger order

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out friend - take care